Multi-threading in Julia to perform functions and write multiple CSV files inside for loops
I am trying to parallelize a for loop in my code, the loop first performs a function and then writes the output in a CSV. When using Threads.@threads I found that only the final iteration CSV was written and not any other.
The code is as follows:
shapes = ["s", "linear", "exp", "expinv"]

Threads.@threads for i in 1:4
    P["SHAPE"] = shapes[i]
    P["DOMINANT"] = true
    f_dom, m_dom, t_dom = prop_plot(P)
    P["DOMINANT"] = false
    f_rec, m_rec, t_rec = prop_plot(P)

    CSV.write(string(filepath, "ML_f_dom_u0250r4872_", shapes[i],".csv"), f_dom)
    CSV.write(string(filepath, "ML_m_dom_u0250r4872_", shapes[i],".csv"), m_dom)
    CSV.write(string(filepath, "ML_t_dom_u0250r4872_", shapes[i],".csv"), t_dom)
    CSV.write(string(filepath, "ML_f_rec_u0250r4872_", shapes[i],".csv"), f_rec)
    CSV.write(string(filepath, "ML_m_rec_u0250r4872_", shapes[i],".csv"), m_rec)
    CSV.write(string(filepath, "ML_t_rec_u0250r4872_", shapes[i],".csv"), t_rec)

Following this I searched online for the issue and saw that it might be due to I/O sharing between threads, the thread suggested using @sync and @async. Using that was not faster than sequentially running the loop.
What would be a possible solution for this?
Minimal example:
shapes = ["s", "linear", "exp", "expinv"]

Threads.@threads for i in 1:4
    case = 1
    df1 = function(case, shapes[i])
    case = 2
    df2 = function(case, shapes[i])

    CSV.write(string(filepath, "df1", shapes[i],".csv"), df1)
    CSV.write(string(filepath, "df2", shapes[i],".csv"), df2)

Output should be the given csv files written in the filepath given.

If the call to CSV.write is the rate-limiting step, you might want to write each thread's output to a different file and then concatenate the files. If the call to function() is rate limiting, you might want to create multiple arrays of dataframe handles of size i, such as df1[i] and df2[i] and have each thread write to its own df1[i] and df2[i], then, once the loop is done, combine all the arrays and write them after the threading is done.

I assume the lack of an end statement after the for is a typo. Can you provide more details about both P, which appears to be a Dict of some kind, and the prop_plot function? On Julia 1.10.3, I am able to run a version of your minimal example without any issues at all on up to 24 threads and enormous table sizes.

This code appears to be modifying a single object (from global variable P) in concurrent threads.
Threads.@threads for i in 1:4
    P["SHAPE"] = shapes[i]
    P["DOMINANT"] = true
    f_dom, m_dom, t_dom = prop_plot(P)
    P["DOMINANT"] = false
    f_rec, m_rec, t_rec = prop_plot(P)
    ...

A possible solution is to make a copy of P in each thread, bind it to a local variable tP, and modify and pass the copy.  (A shallow copy is sufficient if only the top level object is modified.)  Assuming P is a Dict, that might be as follows:
    Threads.@threads for i in 1:4
        local tP = Dict(P)
        tP["SHAPE"] = shapes[i]
        tP["DOMINANT"] = true
        local f_dom, m_dom, t_dom = prop_plot(tP)
        tP["DOMINANT"] = false
        local f_rec, m_rec, t_rec = prop_plot(tP)
        ...

